# Sort an array of objects alphabetically

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects and each objects has a given name and a surname.
These names are written to the object using methods getGivenName and getSurname.

I need to sort the elements in the array in alphabetical order by surname.
how can I do this?

Comment: By using **********. I'm not telling until you tell me have you tried anything ? :)

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/

Comment: no I haven't I have no idea im new to java that's why Im asking

Comment: Check out Java.util.Arrays.  There's one sort routine with your name on it.

Comment: Isn't that +your+ homework?

Comment: Googling "java sorting array" may help.

Comment: Learn to use google. It is good not only for java

Comment: have your class implement Comparable

Answer (score 7):

Your comparator

```
class SampleComparator implements Comparator<YourObject> {
    @Override
    public int compare(YourObject o1, YourObject o2) {

           return o1.getSurname().compareTo(o2.getSurname());
   }
}
```

Your Sorting

```
  Collections.sort(YourList, new SampleComparator())
```

if you need ignore case  then use like

```
  return o1.getSurname().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getSurname());
```

Comment: I have 1000 objects in the array is there a way I can do it more efficiently?

Comment: what makes you think that this is not efficient?

Comment: Note that String.compareTo will compare Strings based on the Unicode value of each character in the strings, which might not be what you want/ expect, depending on your input Strings and locale. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `List` rather than using Array. Your class needs to `implements Comparable interface`.
Please see the code,

### By Implementing Comparable interface

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person>{

private String givenName;
private String surname;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person person1 = new Person("a","b");
    Person person2 = new Person("c","d");
    Person person3 = new Person("e","f");

    List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
    personList.add(person1);
    personList.add(person2);
    personList.add(person3);
    Collections.sort(personList);
    System.out.println(personList);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "WorkSheet [givenName=" + givenName + ", surname=" + surname
            + "]";
}
    public Person() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


public Person(String givenName , String surname) {
    this.givenName = givenName;
    this.surname = surname;
}

public String getGivenName() {
    return givenName;
}

public void setGivenName(String givenName) {
    this.givenName = givenName;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Person o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return o.getSurname().compareTo(this.getSurname());
}
}
```

### By Implementing Comaparator Interface

```
public class Person implements Comparator<Person>{

private String givenName;
private String surname;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person person1 = new Person("a","b");
    Person person2 = new Person("c","d");
    Person person3 = new Person("e","f");

    List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
    personList.add(person1);
    personList.add(person2);
    personList.add(person3);
    Collections.sort(personList , new Person());
    System.out.println(personList);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "WorkSheet [givenName=" + givenName + ", surname=" + surname
            + "]";
}

public Person() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Person(String givenName , String surname) {
    this.givenName = givenName;
    this.surname = surname;
}

public String getGivenName() {
    return givenName;
}

public void setGivenName(String givenName) {
    this.givenName = givenName;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}

@Override
public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return o2.getSurname().compareTo(o1.getSurname());
}
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

When sorting natural language texts, it's recommended to use a [Collator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) and [CollationKeys](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/CollationKey.html). The [String.compareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) method mentioned by other answers will compare Strings based on the Unicode value of each character in the strings, which might not be what you want/ expect, depending on your input Strings and locale.

Note that I wrote [some utility methods](http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/current/docs/api/softsmithy-lib-core/org/softsmithy/lib/text/Localizables.html) to help sorting natural language texts.

E.g. you coud try something like:

```
public class PersonLocalizer implements Localizer<Person> {
    @Override
    public String getDisplayString(Person person, Locale inLocale) {
        return person.getSurname();
    }
} 

[...]

Localizables.sort(new PersonLocalizer (), persons);
```

Maven:

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.softsmithy.lib</groupId>  
    <artifactId>softsmithy-lib-core</artifactId>  
    <version>0.3</version>  
</dependency>
```